# Command to send public key to remote host

Tags: ssh, public-key-encryption

I remember there is a command to send public key to the remote host that I want. I want to use that feature to send one of my public keys to the other host. How can I do that?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You are looking for `ssh-copy-id`.  All this command does is create `.ssh` and `.ssh/authorized_keys` and set their permissions appropriately if they don't exist.  Then it appends your public key to the end of `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: Great. Just run `ssh-copy-id root@server`.

Answer (score 17):

You might be looking for this command:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@hostname 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

It appends your public key to the servers authorized keys.

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/168147/add-public-ssh-key-to-remote-server-in-a-single-command/)

Comment: This is more portable than the accepted answer, since not all systems (I'm looking at you, OS X) have `ssh-copy-id`. Although, personally, I'd modify it slightly to `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@hostname 'tee -a .ssh/authorized_keys'`, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: Looks like ssh-copy-id is part of MacOS Sierra, which is nice.

Answer (score 6):

If your server is already set up to [not accept password-based login](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring#Disable_Password_Authentication), you might get a `Permission denied (publickey)` error.

This is another method to send the key, using `netcat`, so you don't have to authenticate.  It will only work over a local network, but you can use port forwarding to do this over the internet.

On the server:

```
$ nc -l 55555 >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

On the client (replace `HOSTNAME` with the hostname or IP of the server):

```
$ nc HOSTNAME 55555 < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

You can replace `55555` with an open port of your choice.

source: [chat over lan from linux to linux?](https://askubuntu.com/a/62022/533341)

---

Appendix for total newbies: I don't think anyone's mentioned this yet, but if you get `ERROR: failed to open ID file '/home/username/.pub': No such file`, you need to generate a key first.  The Ubuntu help pages have a great guide on [Generating RSA Keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Generating_RSA_Keys).

Answer (score 3):

In other answers there's no example for ssh-copy-id so here it is(first you need to generate the key)

```
ssh-copy-id user@url
```